# finding matching motifs in a sequence and their position

Tags: fasta, python, motifs, sequence

I am trying to find some matching motifs on a sequence, as well as the position that the motif is located in and then output that into a fasta file. The code below shows that the motif `[L*L*L]` is present in the sequence, when I run it returns as "YES" but I do not know where it is positioned.

```py
peptide1="MKFSNEVVHKSMNITEDCSALTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNLAPKNADPTKVQVAVG"

if re.search(r"L*L*L", peptide1):
    print("YES")
else: 
    print("NO")
```

The code that I wrote to find the position is below, but when I run it says invalid syntax. Could you please assist as I am still new in Bioinformatics, and I have no clue whether in the right track or not.

```py
for position in range(len(peptide1)):
    if peptide1[position:].startswith(re.search(r"L*L*L")):
        print(position+1)
```

Lastly once the position of these motifs has been identified, how do I highlight them such that they are visible in the output fasta file.

I am searching for `LxLxL` where `x` can be any amino acid. I used the `*` to indicate to python that it should use any amino acid, but I think I am incorrect. Could you please assist on how I should actually be writing that motif?

Comment: What is the actual pattern you are looking for? `L*L*L*` will match anything at all since `L*` means "0 or more L", so it will match `L` but it will also match X or anything else.

Comment: @terdon, I am searching for LxLxL where x can be any amino acid. I used the * to indicate to python that it should use any amino acid , but I think I am incorrect. Could you please assist on how I should actually be writing that motif.

Comment: @terdon If for example I have a motif LLxxxLxPP, could you please advice on how I am supposed to write it inside re.search or re.finditer? this is where I get confused

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` method do not return a simply boolean but a useful object contains many information:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

peptide1="MKFSNEVVHKSMNITEDCSALTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNLAPKNADPTKVQVAVG"

re_search_result = re.search(r'L*L*L', peptide1)
if re_search_result:
    print("YES")
    motif_start_position=re_search_result.start()
    motif_end_position=re_search_result.end()
    motif_length = re_search_result.end() - re_search_result.start()
    print("Motif start at position: %d" % motif_start_position)
    print("Motif end at position  : %d" % motif_end_position)
    print("SO length is ......... : %d" % motif_length)
    print("The motif is : <%s>" % peptide1[motif_start_position:motif_end_position])
else:
    print("NO")
```

Result is:

```
YES
Motif start at position: 20
Motif end at position  : 488
SO length is ......... : 468
The motif is : <LTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNL>
```

The motif `L*L*L` is a quite strange: `L` zero or many times followed by `L` zero or many times followed by followed by a `L`. It's an equivalent of `L*L`, equivalent of `L+`.

Do you search for `L.*L.*L`, `L[^L]*L[^L]*L` or simply `LLL` ?

Notes:

- When you post code, use block delimited by two ``` (no by two simple `)
- In Python, code indentation is very important, always use spaces (4)

---

If you want to loop over all motifs (like strings), use `findall` method:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

peptide1="MKFSNEVVHKSMNITEDCSALTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNLAPKNADPTKVQVAVG"

re_findall_result = re.findall(r'L[^L]*L[^L]*L', peptide1)
for element in re_findall_result:
    print("Element: <%s>" % element)
```

Result will be:

```
Element: <LTGALL>
Element: <LYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGL>
Element: <LNLNESATTL>
Element: <LGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNIL>
Element: <LDLKVHL>
Element: <LSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSL>
Element: <LVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKL>
Element: <LEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFL>
Element: <LIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWEL>
```

---

If you want all find objects like with `search` method, use `finditer` method:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re

peptide1="MKFSNEVVHKSMNITEDCSALTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNLAPKNADPTKVQVAVG"

re_findall_result = re.finditer(r'L[^L]*L[^L]*L', peptide1)
for element in re_findall_result:
    print("peptide1[%s:%s]=<%s>" % (element.start(), element.end(), peptide1[element.start():element.end()]))
```

Result will be:

```
peptide1[20:26]=<LTGALL>
peptide1[39:69]=<LYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGL>
peptide1[90:100]=<LNLNESATTL>
peptide1[101:163]=<LGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNIL>
peptide1[248:255]=<LDLKVHL>
peptide1[278:296]=<LSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSL>
peptide1[378:404]=<LVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKL>
peptide1[407:443]=<LEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFL>
peptide1[449:469]=<LIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWEL>
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I have another question, if for example the motif is written as LLxxLxPP, where x can be any amino acid, how must I write it? I think that is one of the things that confuses me

Comment: So if I have LxxLxPP where x can be any amino acid, how must I write it inside the re.finditer ? This is where I get confused

Comment: @thole in regular expressions, `*` means "0 or more of the previous character". To match any character, you want `.`. Also, `[ABC]` means "find either `A` or `B` or `C`". So the actual pattern you want is `r'L.L.L'` but of course that will also match `LLLLL`.

Comment: @terdon thank you, that makes a lot of sense. So if I had a motif LxxLxP then it would be r'L..L.P'

Comment: Yes, exactly right @thole.

Comment: if you are interested by Regular Expression (RegEx) in Python, see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp